# Passing and Storing Strings

Tags: c#, wpf, string, variables

I'm trying to pass some strings(className & classID) and store them in a different variable(classNameClicked & classIDClicked) based on what hyperlink the user clicked.

Here is my code behind(C#) for creating the hyperlinks:

```
TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();                                        
txt.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;                                   
txt.Foreground = Brushes.Black;                                         
txt.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Times New Roman");                       
txt.FontSize = 25;                                                      
txt.Margin = new Thickness(5);

TextBlock ClassID = new TextBlock();
ClassID.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
ClassID.Text = classID;

Run run = new Run(className);                                           
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink(run);                                    
link.Click += Link_Click;                                               
txt.Inlines.Add(ClassID);
txt.Inlines.Add(link);

myStackPanel.Children.Add(txt);                                         
frame.Content = myStackPanel;
```

I was able to pass the string from the className to classNameClicked by extracting the text from the hyperlink using the code below:

```
private void Link_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     classNameClicked = ((sender as Hyperlink).Inlines.FirstInline as Run).Text;
     classIDClicked = (sender as Textblock).Text;

     Class_Page class_page = new Class_Page();
     NavigationService.Navigate(class_page);
}
```

However, I cant seem to figure out how to extract the string from classID.
Please help.

Comment: You're going to get a null reference exception because the sender can't be both a `Hyperlink` AND a `TextBox`.  I would have separate `Click` handlers for each control and have the rest of the (shared) code in a separate method.

Comment: @DStanley I suppose the OP wants to get `className` and `classID` in one go when the `Hyperlink` was clicked. Two separate `Click` handlers would probably be no help in this scenario. But as mentioned by Mat, MVVM would surely be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to reference the parent of your `Hyperlink`.

So instead of

```
classNameClicked = ((sender as Hyperlink).Inlines.FirstInline as Run).Text;
classIDClicked = (sender as TextBlock).Text;
```

you can write

```
Hyperlink link = sender as Hyperlink;
classNameClicked = (link.Inlines.FirstInline as Run).Text;
classIDClicked = (link.Parent as TextBlock).Inlines.OfType<Run>().First().Text;
```

If you don't want to use LINQ you could also write:

```
classIDClicked = ((link.Parent as TextBlock).Inlines.FirstInline as Run).Text;
```

But I have the same overall opinion as Mat in the comments. This is really ugly and MVVM would be the way to go for writing much cleaner code.

Additionally you should probably add some null checking too.

**Edit as requested in the comment:**
If you don't want to display the `classID` in your GUI then you could hide it in the `Tag` of the `Hyperlink`:

```
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink(run);
link.Tag = classID;
link.Click += Link_Click;
```

And then just get it in your `Click` handler:

```
classIDClicked = link.Tag as string;
```

You don't need a hidden `TextBlock` for that.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! It works! I know that I should have learned MVVM but I'm already way in to the project and the deadline is already near.

Comment: If i could ask one last question, Is it possible to hide the "classID" and still be able to pass it to "classIDClicked" and how? I edited my post.

Comment: @syn3rgy I've edited my answer. Glad I could help you. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works again! You saved my life.